# MVC VIew Model Loses Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvvm

I was developing this website in the development server. 
These codes are working perfectly find in the development database.

However, after I publish to production server. The Post function AjaxList is getting the value of PageSize = 0.

I manage to solve the issue by adding this code in my form.

```
    <% = Html.HiddenFor(Function(x) x.PageSize) %>
```

Just that I don't understand why is it working in development application server. But not in production application server. In development server it can proceed the form without "hiddenFor".
Does anyone can enlighten me on this?

Below is the snippet of my codes.

**View model:**

```
    Public Class QACertificateViewModel
            Private _PageSize As Integer
            Public Property PageSize() As Integer
                Get
            Return _PageSize
                End Get
                Set(ByVal value As Integer)
                    _PageSize = value
                End Set
            End Property
    End Class
```

**Controller:**

```
    Public Function List() As ViewResult
        Dim vm As New QACertificateViewModel
        vm.PageSize = 15
        Return View(vm)
    End Function

    <HttpPost()>
    Public Function AjaxList(vm As QACertificateViewModel) As ActionResult
        Dim pageSize As Integer = vm.PageSize ' the pageSize is 0, it should be 15
    End Function
```

**View (.ascx):**

```
    <% Using (Html.BeginForm("AjaxList", "QACertificate", FormMethod.Post, New With {.class = "AjaxForm"}))%>

            <%= Html.Encode(Model.QADocHdr.DocumentNo)%>
    <% End Using%>
```

Comment: Not quite sure how you can claim that it works in development. If you never generate a form control for the `PageSize` property in the view, then its value will never be posted and the value will always be `0` (the default for `int`).

Comment: I manage to get PageSize = 15 in development server. Same source codes go to production server and it becomes PageSize = 0. :(

Comment: @StephenMuecke I agree with you. I just curious why does it behave differently though.

Comment: What you are claiming is impossible unless you where using other code you have not shown (for example adding the value as a route parameter in the form). A form posts the name/pair values of its successful controls so if you never included the hidden input, then it would not have been ent to the server, and your server is not psychic, so the value would be `0`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I'm sure it's the same code. To confirm that, I changed the database connection string directly (Web.config in Visual studio) from development to production, means only IP address and database login credentials are different in my case.